# Send probe requests without waiting for an answer in C

Tags: c, network-programming

for a project I am working on, I have to regularly send probe requests (~ 10 every 10 ms) for a chosen SSID.

Currently I am doing this with the following code:

```
char *args[] = {"iwlist", INTERFACE, "scan", "essid", ssid, (char *) NULL};
runQuietlyNonblocking(args);
```

where `runQuietlyNonblocking` runs the command in args with execvp and fork without waiting for the new thread to finish.

But since iwlist scan waits for probe answers and this takes more time than I need to create new probe requests, the probe requests get send but I got about 10000 threads after about half an hour and the program crashes due to memory shortage.

I am working on a raspberry pi with raspbian lite installed.
Is there a better way to send probe requests without the need to wait for an answer? Can i send probe requests manually or tell iwlist not to look for responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options. As far as I know popen() with "w" parameter does not wait for command execution, though it forks the process and pclose() will wait until command executes. system() just waits for command execution, but you might try feeding it to shell like this

```
system("iwlist wlan0 scan &")
```

That is, if you are stuck with iwlist. 
As an alternative you can try using wpa_supplicant. It has a "scan" interface and "scan_results", first one sends request while the later gives out results.

```
  for (;;)
  {
    FILE *fp = popen ("wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan", "w");
    if (fp)
      pclose (fp);
    sleep (1);
  }
```

(implying wpa_supplicant is up and running).

Last but not least, there are drivers which allow doing background scanning with their own interfaces, have seen it on proprietary Redpine driver.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try if wpa_supplicant is quicker.

With system or popen I'm having the same issues (tried them before I got to my current solution) as my call already does not wait for command execution.
The problem is not that I have to wait for command execution, the problem is that the command execution of a new thread takes more time than the time I wait between starting another thread.

Comment: @FreddyUnicorn maybe, the problem is actually about thread management rather than "a better way to send probe requests"? I don't remember seeing any regulations on minimal probe request intervals, it means that it heavily depends on module/driver/interface tool. If you no matter what need those fast requests, maybe try to build another driver for your module. If it won't won't help, guess you have to hold your threads: wait for request to end and join thread cleanly.

Comment: @FreddyUnicorn also, I have had my share of problems with iwlist scanning. What I was doing: every 10 secs a thread spawned, called an iwlist scan and closed afterwards. It worked flawlessly for 4-5 hours, no unneeded processes in "top". I left my board for overnight testing and in the morning I've had a bunch of shells with iwlist stuck inside them. That was ugly, good God my driver had a special interface to set background scan with interval(min was 3 seconds though, but I needed it once per 10 secs so it was ok). Not much of a help, just my experience.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay of my answer:
I tried to use wpa_supplicant, but unfortunately, I have to use the same interface for other uses as well (a software access point for example) and this seems to be not working with wpa_supplicant.
I'll accept your answer, because it seems to work if you want to use the interface with wpa_supplicant only, but I will keep on looking for a better answer.